# Duplicate Entry Error for Update Query within a Procedure

Tags: mysql, loops, procedure

I am trying to do an update MySQL query that goes like:

```
UPDATE   task, category
SET      assigned=@date_cur, task.id=(SELECT @last_id := task.id)
WHERE    task.category=category.id AND category.parent=@super_id
ORDER BY task.due
LIMIT    1;
```

And I get the following error :

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '108' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Not sure why this is happening, it works fine when I do a simple query with a similar WHERE, such as:

```
SELECT task.title FROM task, category WHERE task.category=category.id 
AND category.parent=@super_id
```

I think it's worth mentioning that this is happening within nested while loops in a procedure, but I've been able to do other update queries just fine, it's only when I do `WHERE task.category=category.id AND category.parent=@super_id` when the error pops up.